# Status 403 when using the LWP::Simple

Tags: perl

Below is the simple code that I used:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = "http://automanga.com/uploads/manga/bleach/chapters/12/09.jpg";
my $file = "09.jpg"; 
my $rc = getstore($url, $file);


if (is_error($rc)) 
{
    print "getstore failed with $rc\n";
}
```

The link is working as I try it in the browser but somehow it just return `403` status.

Appreciate for your advice on this.

Comment: Do you understand what 403 means?  Your code must provide the required credential to access the resource.

Comment: Does it means that i do not have permission to access the resource on this? So it means that the code is correct but just due to the permission stuff?

Comment: The site is expecting authentication credentials on every request, and while your browser provides them (you had to login, right?) your Perl code is not providing them, so the server is refusing to service the request.  You should find a tutorial on HTTP and read the parts about authentication and authorization carefully.

Comment: as i can manually save the image by entering the url in the browser without any login needed. those image are actually comic and what i plan to do is it automate to save all the pages into local instead to save it one by one. So may i know that do i need to fill up my prel code on this?

Comment: okok noted. I will look into the HTTP on the authentication as your suggested.

Comment: You may have logged in at one time in the past and the session is long-lasting.  Alternatively, the site defends against automated downloaders by checking the `User-agent:` header.

Comment: I just tried the URL and was able to see the image, so it is probably checking `User-agent:` and refusing to serve images to non-browsers.

Comment: If thats the case then there is no way to save the image with non-browser without a proper authentication for that url. Appreciate for your advice on this.

Comment: *If thats the case then there is no way to save the image with non-browser without a proper authentication for that url* No, that's not true. If the server is checking the User-Agent header, then you just need to change that header in the request that you send.

Answer (score 3):

The book *LWP and Perl* ([available legally for free online](http://lwp.interglacial.com)) is a great introduction to the LWP toolkit. In particular, the section [Adding Extra Request Header Lines](http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch11_02.htm) has a useful discussion of the kind of problem you're having here.

Unfortunately, LWP::Simple isn't up to the job. You'll want to switch to [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) and [HTTP::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request) instead. Then you can use the `agent()` method on your LWP::UserAgent object and `header()` on your HTTP::Request object to craft exactly the request that you need.

**Update:** I played with this a bit during my lunch break. Looks like they are blocking on the UserAgent string. Just changing that to anything will make it work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent('Foo');

my $url = 'http://automanga.com/uploads/manga/bleach/chapters/12/09.jpg';
my $file = '09.jpg';

my $resp = $ua->get($url);

if ($resp->is_error) {
  die $resp->status_line, "\n";
}

open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
binmode $fh;
print $fh $resp->decoded_content;
```